# UIPopoverController dismisses without delegate call

Tags: iphone, ios, mkmapview, uipopovercontroller

I have a map view which i am adding and removing `annotations` from based on a switch in a `popovercontroller`. When i touch outside the `popover`, it dismisses correctly and calls the `delegate` method `popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:`  The problem that i am having is that when i toggle the switch in the `popover` (touching within the popover view), if i am removing the `annotations` from the map it behaves correctly and the popover stays visible but if i am adding the `annotations` to the map view, then the `popover` disappears and the `delegate` method is not called. Has anyone come across this behavior before?

The only difference between the on and off code of the switch is that one removes the `annotations` from an array, while the other adds the `annotations`. This is only a problem when adding the `annotations` to the map view. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

This is how the `popover` is displayed:

```
-(IBAction)toggleMapFiltersView:(id)sender
 {
    LayerPopoverViewController *popOverViewController = [[LayerPopoverViewController alloc] init];
    [popOverViewController setDelegate:self];
    [popOverViewController setBranchesShowing:branchesShowing];
    [popOverViewController setSchoolsShowing:schoolsShowing];

    [layersButton setSelected:YES];

    popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc]   initWithContentViewController:popOverViewController];


    [popoverController setDelegate:self];
    [popOverViewController release];
    [popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:layersButton.frame
                                       inView:[self view] 
                     permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny 
                                     animated:YES];
}
```

This is the method that is being called from the popover view:

```
-(IBAction)toggleSchools:(id)sender
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(didChangeSchoolsDisplaySettingWithVisible:)])
    {
        if ([schoolsSwitch isOn])
        {
        [self.delegate didChangeSchoolsDisplaySettingWithVisible:YES];
             self.schoolsShowing = YES;
        }
        else
        {
            [self.delegate didChangeSchoolsDisplaySettingWithVisible:NO];
            self.schoolsShowing = NO;
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the method it is referring to:

```
-(void)didChangeSchoolsDisplaySettingWithVisible:(BOOL)visible
{
    if (visible == YES)
    {
        schoolsShowing = YES;
        if (self.schoolArray != nil && [self.schoolArray count] > 0)
        {
            for (MySchool *school in self.schoolArray)
            {
                [mapView addAnnotation:school];
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        schoolsShowing = NO;
        for (id<MKAnnotation> annotation in mapView.annotations)
        {
            if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MySchool class]])
            {
                [mapView removeAnnotation:annotation];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post some code, so we can look at what is happening?

Comment: added the two methods involved

Comment: Please show us how the popover is set up and displayed.

Comment: have added the setup for the popover

Comment: So when you call `-(IBAction)toggleSchools` from within the UIPopoverController it dismisses without calling the didDismiss? Seems to me that is indeed unexpected behavior. The only reason the dismiss callback should not be called is when you programmatically dismiss it yourself. (see Apple doc for the UIPopoverControllerDelegate)

Is there a call in some underlying code telling the popover to dismiss? Not getting any memory warnings I presume? No other weird erratic behavior?

Comment: yes. But only the second time toggle schools is called. If toggle schools is called and it removes the annotations from the map, then the popover doesn't dismiss. When you call it the second time to add the annotations back onto the map, the popover then dismisses itself without calling the delegate method. No memory warnings, not dismissing the popover programatically from anywhere either. I was thinking that it might have something to do with the annotations being added onto the map, perhaps this somehow confuses the popover and causes it to dissappear.

Comment: the popover gets dismissed any time i add an annotation to the map view which is behind the visible popover. I have a couple of different methods that have similar functionality and the result is the same. Has anyone come across this before?

Comment: Are you using ARC? There's a good chance it's releasing your controllers when you still need them, hence the delegate releasing. Try assigning your controllers to properties and see what happens.

Comment: Idea: Override `-[UIPopoverViewController dismissPopoverAnimated:]`, set a break point, and look at the stack trace.  That should tell you where it's getting dismissed.  Once you have that, we can discuss why your delegate isn't getting called.

Comment: @NonatomicRetain He's clearly not using ARC as there is a release message in that first block of code. In any case, the code posted here is not sufficient to divine the problem; the popover is created and displayed with a retainCount of 1, so it shouldn't be deallocated randomly without calling `shouldDismiss`. @Olie has a good suggestion; you can also return right at the start of `toggleSchools` to see if it's unrelated to what you're doing with your mapView.

Answer (score 0):

Why use popovers in the first place? it's will be easier for you to control a customView.

You can create a custom popupView, and place it just above the coordinates you like.
the popup has a dismiss button, and delegate call for this action.

Here's some code (in this example, the coordinates are from a marker, and mapView is google's). You will also have to convert the coordinates to a CGPoint.

```
UIAnnotationView *annotation = [[UIAnnotationView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];
                  annotation.delegate = self;
                  annotation.tag = 101;

CGPoint point = [mapView.projection pointForCoordinate:marker.position];
        annotation.origin =  CGPointMake(point.x - annotation.width / 2, point.y - annotation.height - MARKER_DEFAULT_SIZE);
        [mapView addSubview:annotation];
```

UIAnnotaionView closeButtonClicked Delegate:

```
- (void)annotationViewCloseButtonClicked:(UIAnnotationView *)annotationView
{
    [[_mapView viewWithTag:101] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

To dismiss the popupView when touching other points in the map override this delegate:

```
- (void)mapView:(GMSMapView *)mapView didTapAtCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coordinate
{
    [[_mapView viewWithTag:101] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Comment: Popovers *do* have a sort of system-ish feel to them.

Comment: True, but its a valid alternative. 
plus, finding a popover-like design is easy i guess..

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried one more delegate method

```
- (BOOL)popoverControllerShouldDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController {
    // do some stuff here and decide whether to dismiss or not
    return YES; //or No depending on your condition
}
```

It will ask you whether you want to dismiss the popOver Controller or not.
It is called each time the popoverviewcontroller is about to dismiss

Otherwise you can call a method upon adding of annotation to mapview. Anyway you know that pop over is dismissing. Do the same work when the pop over controller is dismisses. As you are doing with

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
```

I hope this might help you